# how separate string into key/value pair in dart?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, keyvaluepair

how can a string be  separated  into key/value pair in dart? The  string is separated by a `"="`. And how can the pair value be extracted?

```
    main(){
  
  var stringTobeSeparated = ['ab = cd','ef = gh','ld = kg'];

Map<String ,dynamic> map = {};
    for (String s in stringTobeSeparated) {
          var keyValue = s.split("=");
    //failed to add to a map , to many positiona arguments error
         map.addAll(keyValue[0],keyValue[1]);
      
        
        }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: i'm retrieving data from an api i need put it in pair value format

Comment: What's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: if your familiar with java its possible retrieve key value after separating a string. So i'm asking for similar thing to do in dart

Comment: You show some code but you make no mention of the results of that attempt or why it's not working.

Comment: i edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split() function gives you a List of Strings, so you just need to check if the length of this List is equal to 2 and then you can add those values in a Map like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = {};
for (String s in stringTobeSeparated) {
    var list = s.split("=");
    if(list.length == 2) {
        // list[0] is your key and list[1] is your value
        map[list[0]] = list[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` for this, the accepted answer is correct, but since your string looks like this

```
var stringTobeSeparated = ['ab = cd','ef = gh','ld = kg'];
```

I would rather use regex to remove spaces from final result (replace the line with `split` with this):

```
var list = s.split(RegExp(r"\s+=\s+"));
```